# how can i installed my windows form application on my computer or another computer

Tags: c#, winforms

[i developed this app in Visual studio.i need to installed this app like setup.on my computer or on another computer.please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzYdt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to try [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/).

Using InstallShield you can select framework to be included in your Setup also you can customize your setup for Target Computers.

Comment: u just solved my big problem.tnx.